# Jenkinsfile stash subdirectory and files exclude parent directory

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have got a directory structure that I want to stash using Jenkinsfile. The directory structure is `build/demo/**/*`. I want to stash just the sub directory and all files/folders underneath it, i.e that is `demo/**/*`.

So when I `unstash`. I would want to get `demo` as parent folder and all the folders and files underneath it.

I have tried the following ant-style include patterns. But I got the same undesirable result every time.

```
stash includes: "**/demo/**", name: 'demoBuild'
stash includes: "build/demo/**", name: 'demoBuild'
```

Results from above pattern:
`build/demo/**/*`

Answer (score 0):

This might get you what you want:

```
stash includes: "build/demo/**", name: 'demoBuild'
...
unstash name: 'demoBuild'
sh "mv build/demo . && rmdir build/"
```